# (esp 32) http.GET() is so slow

Tags: c++, rest, get, esp32

I want to get data from REST API by an esp32 and turning on and off LED lights(GPIO 26 and 27).
Here is my code :

```cpp
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "ssidName";
const char* password = "password";

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
pinMode(26, OUTPUT);
pinMode(27, OUTPUT);

digitalWrite(26, LOW);
digitalWrite(27, LOW);

WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi");
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
Serial.print(".");
}
}

void loop() {
if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){

HTTPClient http;

http.begin("https://retoolapi.dev/XB1y0H/data"); 
int httpCode = http.GET();
   

if (httpCode > 0){
  String payload = http.getString(); 
        
  payload.replace('[', ' ');
  payload.replace(']', ' ');
  char json[500];
  payload.toCharArray(json, 500);
  StaticJsonDocument<1024> doc;
  deserializeJson(doc, json);
  String led1 = doc["rele1"];
  Serial.print("led1 :");
  Serial.println(led1);
  if(led1== "1") digitalWrite(26, HIGH);
  else digitalWrite(26, LOW);
  String led2 = doc["rele2"];
  if(led2 == "1") digitalWrite(27, HIGH);
  else digitalWrite(27, LOW);
  Serial.print("led2 :");
  Serial.println(led2);
}

http.end();  
}else{
Serial.println("Check your internet connection");
}



}
```

It works but the problem is , it is so slow ; http.GET() takes approximately 2 seconds to be executed and I dont know why ... 
Is it because of API ?
Is there any better solution ? I've heard about webSocket but I'm not sure about it .
Is it good and easy to integrate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to do that by **Websokcet** .  
you have to make http persistent connection , **HTTP client library** in **idf** is good but your server has to support it , the better practice is **websocket**.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is the TLS handshake in establishing an HTTPS connection and its crypto math, which does tend to take approximately 2 seconds on the little ESP32.

The solution is to not create a new HTTPS connection with each query and close it when done. For this you need persistent HTTPS connections which are supported by the [HTTP client library](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/esp_http_client.html#persistent-connections) in Espressif ESP IDF or alternatively websockets. Maybe there's a library in Arduino to do this, I don't know. Anyway, once you pick a library then open a connection once and keep it open for subsequent queries.

Comment: great , Can you give me a sample code about it ? I'm not familiar with HTTP client library.

Comment: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/b531745a11adafffc5558ef7ee2b9f65ba0806ba/examples/protocols/esp_http_client/main

Comment: I have only used arduino ide for esp32 and it was pretty easy , but idf seems so crazy.

Comment: ESP IDF has good documentation, examples, etc. If you work through them, you'll get the hang of it. If you don't want to do that, there probably exist solutions on Arduino also, I just don't know them.

Answer (score 1):

The request is slow due to the ESP32 having to create the TLS (HTTPS) connection everytime which takes up to 2 seconds.

To resolve this, you can re-use the TLS connection for future requests ("persistent HTTPS connections").

Please see below a snippet of how to re-use connections and speed up requests with ESP32, which has been copied from [source](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/examples/ReuseConnection/ReuseConnection.ino)

```
HTTPClient http;

void setup() {
    // allow reuse (if server supports it)
    http.setReuse(true);
}
```